# ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver JAVA JSP

Tags: java, jsp, excepciones, mysqlconnector.jar

Problema:

Tengo un metodo de tipo ArrayList que retorna un objeto del mismo, pero cuando lo invoco en el JSP me da el siguiente error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
public ArrayList<Producto> con()throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    qry = "SELECT * FROM productos";
    st = con.conectar().createStatement();
    rst = st.executeQuery(qry);
    while (rst.next()){
        list.add(0,rst.getInt("ID_PRODUCTO"));
        list.add(1,rst.getString("COD_COLOR"));
        list.add(2,rst.getString("COD_SIZE"));
        list.add(3,rst.getString("NOMBRE"));
        list.add(4,rst.getDouble("PRECIO"));
        list.add(5,rst.getString("IMAGEN"));
    }
    con.conectar().close();
    return list;
}
```

y en el JSP lo llamo de la siguiente fotma:

```
ProductoM prod;
prod = new ProductoM();
ArrayList arrayprod = prod.con();
```

Es entonces cuando llamo al metodo, pero me da el error de que no encuentra el driver del conector mysql.

Esta es mi clase de coneccion:

```
public class Coneccion {

public Connection conectar() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/runner","root","");
    return con;

}
```

}

Cree una clase e hice un main donde llame los datos de la base de datos y todo me funciono bien, volvi a cargar el conector, pero nada, en el JSP sigue saliendome el error de que no encuentra el Driver.

Nota: Estoy usando Itellij IDE, el conector : mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar

Error completo:

```
Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP        page [/catalogo.jsp] at line [17]

14: <%
15:     ProductoM prod;
16:     prod = new ProductoM();
17:     ArrayList arrayprod = prod.con();
18:     int cont = 0;
19: %>
20: <section>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
org.apache.jsp.catalogo_jsp._jspService(catalogo_jsp.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
model.Coneccion.conectar(Coneccion.java:9)
model.ProductoM.con(ProductoM.java:94)
org.apache.jsp.catalogo_jsp._jspService(catalogo_jsp.java:126)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: valida que en el WAR efectivamente se esté incluyendo la librería en WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1):

El JSP que ejecutas se ha desplegado en un contenedor (¿Apache Tomcat, quizá?), y seguramente ahí no tengas añadido el jar con las clases del driver. Busca la carpeta **lib** dentro de tu contenedor y pon ahí tu *JAR*. Otra opción es añadir el JAR a tu fichero WAR, asegúrate de que tengas el driver como dependencia de tu proyecto.

Si estás aprendiendo a usar JSP con estas pruebas, te recomiendo que [no uses código Java dentro de un JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), el código es complicado de mantener o depurar.

Si ese código es parte de una aplicación *real*, puedes tener muchos problemas si creas una conexión para cada consulta, deberías usar un [*pool de conexiones*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).